# On Big Sur, contentFilters not working for NSProgressIndicator. NSProgressIndicator is not visible when set contentFilters

Tags: swift, macos, macos-big-sur

To set the colour of NSProgressIndicator I have used contentFilters. It works fine on Catalina and Mojave. But on Big Sur, non of the contentFilters property works. I am trying to achieve round progress indicator.

Below code work fine with Catalina and Mojave, but does not work on Big Sur. The progress indicator colour is not reflecting.

```
extension NSProgressIndicator {
   
  func set(tintColor: NSColor) {
    guard let adjustedTintColor = tintColor.usingColorSpace(.deviceRGB) else {
      contentFilters = []
      DDLogVerbose("guard is returned")
      return
    }
     
    let tintColorRedComponent = adjustedTintColor.redComponent
    let tintColorGreenComponent = adjustedTintColor.greenComponent
    let tintColorBlueComponent = adjustedTintColor.blueComponent
     
    let tintColorMinComponentsVector = CIVector(x: tintColorRedComponent, y: tintColorGreenComponent, z: tintColorBlueComponent, w: 0.0)
    let tintColorMaxComponentsVector = CIVector(x: tintColorRedComponent, y: tintColorGreenComponent, z: tintColorBlueComponent, w: 1.0)
     
    let colorClampFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorClamp")!
    colorClampFilter.setDefaults()
    colorClampFilter.setValue(tintColorMinComponentsVector, forKey: "inputMinComponents")
    colorClampFilter.setValue(tintColorMaxComponentsVector, forKey: "inputMaxComponents")
    DDLogVerbose("color is returned")

    contentFilters = [colorClampFilter]
  }
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to find the correct sublayer in the progress indicator's layer hierarchy. For me, it seemed like it was the sublayer with a `CGImage` set as the layers contents and with the image's color space set to the RGB color space. Applying the `CIFalseColor` filter worked for this layer. However, this might change in any macOS release.

Here is some Objective-C sample code (taken from a `NSProgressIndicator` subclass):

```objectivec
- (void)updateLayer
{
    [super updateLayer];
    
    CALayer *imageLayer = self.progressBarLayer;
    if (imageLayer && !imageLayer.filters.count) {
        CIFilter *colorFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIFalseColor"];
        [colorFilter setDefaults];
        CIColor *color = [[CIColor alloc] initWithColor:NSColor.redColor];
        [colorFilter setValue:color forKey:@"inputColor0"];
        [colorFilter setValue:color forKey:@"inputColor1"];
        imageLayer.filters = @[colorFilter];
    }
}

- (nullable CALayer *)progressBarLayer
{
    if (!self.layer)
        return nil;
    
    // Iterate all layers, try to find layer with RGB image
    NSMutableArray<CALayer *> *sublayers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.layer.sublayers];
    while (sublayers.count) {
        CALayer *layer = sublayers[0];
        [sublayers removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        [sublayers addObjectsFromArray:layer.sublayers];
        
        id contents = layer.contents;
        if (contents && CFGetTypeID((__bridge CFTypeRef)(contents)) == CGImageGetTypeID()) {
            CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGImageGetColorSpace((__bridge CGImageRef)contents);
            CGColorSpaceModel model = CGColorSpaceGetModel(colorSpace);
            if (model == kCGColorSpaceModelRGB)
                return layer;
        }
    }
    
    return nil;
}
```